# React how to avoid an error when sending a fetch request?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to send a fetch request.

Faced a number of CORS bugs, After setting mode: 'no-cors',

the request was sent, with http status code 200, but when trying to get a response, an error appears in the console:

> Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of input. Server headers are set in both files.

Please tell me how you can get around this error?

api-local/auth:

index.php

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

require "connect.php";
require "functions.php";

$type = $_GET['q'];

if($type === 'dict') {
  getDict($db);
  }

if($type === 'auth') {
  postAuth();
}

?>
```

login.php

```
?php

 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
 header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

include_once 'config/database.php';
include_once 'objects/user.php';
...
```

localhost:3000:

action.js

````
 fetch(`http://api-local/auth`, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify({ "email": `${email}`, "password": `${pass}`})
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => console.log(response ));
    ```
````

Comment: You don't need `mode: 'no-cors',`. What's your response, is it JSON?

Comment: use like this `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api-local/auth` and remove `mode`

Comment: @NishargShah why does he need `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` if he already enabled cross-origin resource sharing?

Comment: so you are entering wrong data

Comment: how an http request has an http status code. status codes are for http respone?